# MarkLogic stemming basic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have my database language set to `en` and `stemmed searches` to `Basic`, `word searches` disabled.

For a document like the following i exected queries only to work for the first/shortest stem to be found (as described [here](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/324/0/stemming-and-element-value-query)). The stem for `further` returns 3 stems: further, farther and far. I checked this with

```
cts:stem("further")
```

So as Basic stemmed searches should only index the shortest stem, i expected a search with `farther` not to find my document. But this is not the case.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $doc := 
<doc>
  <title>further</title>
</doc>

return xdmp:document-insert('test.xml', $doc);

cts:search(doc(), cts:word-query("farther")); // finds my document

cts:stem("further")
```

Is there anything im am misunderstanding? Why does a search for `farther` find a doc with `further` even if it is not the shortest/first stem?

Also a search for the third stem finds my document, even if with a "unstemmed" option (`word searches` enabled in this case).

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:word-query("further", ("unstemmed")));
```

Using MarkLogic 9.0-7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal index in MarkLogic has multiple parts. There is one for stemmed searches, and one for unstemmed/wildcarded searches. The stemmed part of the index contains stems, but the unstemmed part has the unstemmed tokens. That is why the unstemmed search on the actual value finds a match.

About the stemmed search: as you can read in the documentation of [`cts:stem`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:stem), that function returns all stems regardless of database setting. However, the order in which it returns them is important. `cts:stem("further")` returns `far, further, farther`, `cts:stem("farther")` returns `far, farther, further`, and `cts:stem("far")` returns `far`.

From what I understood is that basic stemming takes the first item returned by cts:stem, and uses that for indexing. As you can read from above, that means it uses `far` for `further`, `farther`, as well as for `far`. Advanced stemming would allow you to find `further` when doing a stemmed search for `farther`, and vice versa.

Some more detail is available in the Search guide in the section: ['Stemming in MarkLogic'](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/stemming#id_37129)

HTH!

Comment: That helped. Thanks for the explanation.